# how can I implement a qr code in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, include

I used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
var qrcode = new QRCode("test", {
  text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  colorDark : "#000000",
  colorLight : "#ffffff",
  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

but it didn't work out for me.. did I include it false or something?

Comment: Are you doing anything with the result?

Comment: Well you do need `<div id="test"> </div>` somewhere before the function, you are aware of that?

Comment: Google Charts has a QR Code generator: `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=128x128&chl=http%3A//jindo.dev.naver.com/collie&chld=H|0" />` https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?csw=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this way. Have a `<div>` that will have QR Code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Then initialize this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("test"), "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie");
</script>
```

In your script, it should be:

```
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("test"), {
  text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
  width: 128,
  height: 128,
  colorDark : "#000000",
  colorLight : "#ffffff",
  correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```